# Mouse: why is it the same ?

Tags: mouse

In terms of hardware evolution, in 10 years we've  improved a lot in processors, monitors, video cards, and many other examples.

In the other hand, the mouse is pretty the same we got 10 years ago.

Is there a reason for that ??

Comment: Can you think of any improvements that would actually work?

Comment: well, touch i guess. that is why apple stock is so high :-)

Comment: But will the touch kill the mouse ? I am not sure of that. I think the trackball was an excellent invention, but I should be the only one who enjoyed it.

Comment: @Diogothenoob: Are you still using a ball mouse?

Comment: Mouse have improved in terms of material, ergonomy, sensor technology, aditional buttons, but in essence they are pretty the same. I am using a laser one, but I think you get the point.

Comment: [5 Best Gaming Mouse for Power Gamers](http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2011/09/best-gaming-mouse/)

Comment: I would rather we get rid of mouse and touch altogether, like kinect, just use my gestures and even thoughts, some day.

Comment: There was trackball, but left the market (consumer market, some pro applications and hardware still use it). Mouse is pretty easy and effective.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's pretty much as efficient/improved as it can get.

There are some improvements, such as infrared sensing and wireless, but otherwise, the mouse is very good at what it does.

Serously, can you think of any useful improvements to it that haven't been already implemented?

Comment: I cant think of any improvements, but this does not mean that improvements could not be done, think of it.

Comment: @ topic, the trackball was an interesting stuff